# applying conditional logic

Tags: sql

I have devices that can appear in a number of files due to poor logic and user error outside of the database. I know which file it should be in based on a set of rules and I'm looking to automate this with a third Boolean or binary response type column.

This is an example of how the table looks. You can see how the devices can appear in more than one file.

```
device | file
A        1862
A        1880
B        1880  
C        1901
C        1880
```

The rules to apply would be like this:

- if device in 1862 then true (regardless of whether it is also elsewhere)
- if device in 1880 check it does not also in 1862 or 1901, then true
- if device in 1901 then true (regardless of whether it is also elsewhere)

I've tried using a self join logic with case when, but can't seem to get it right.

This is what I want to end up with.

```
device | file | Correct
A        1862   Yes  --it exists here so we don't care if it exists elsewhere
A        1880   No   --because it exists in 1862
B        1880   Yes  --because it does not exist in 1901 or 1862
C        1901   Yes  --it exists here so we don't care if it exists elsewhere
C        1880   No   --because it also exists in 1901
```

I only need a correct output i.e. I don't need to be correcting the tables at this stage; this is to prove that the tables need correcting :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CASE for the 3 rules:

```
select t.*, 
  case 
    when file in (1862, 1901) then 'Yes'
    when file = 1880 and not exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where device = t.device and file in (1862, 1901)
    ) then 'Yes'
    else 'No'
  end Correct
from tablename t;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vYK5LdDQcawzBpxTVsd4wk/0).
Results:

```
| device | file | Correct |
| ------ | ---- | ------- |
| A      | 1862 | Yes     |
| A      | 1880 | No      |
| B      | 1880 | Yes     |
| C      | 1901 | Yes     |
| C      | 1880 | No      |
```

Comment: This worked great. Actually it was very close to what I was doing, but following your method helped me to find the clause I'd forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when file in (1862, 1901) then 'Yes'
             when file = 1880 and
                  sum(case when file in (1862, 1901) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by device) = 0
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end) as flag 
from t;
```